# Induction and Restriction of Scalars

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I have been reading Brown's Book, Cohomology of groups and i cant quite see why a certain proposition is true, so he claims that

> $Res_K^GInd_H^GM \cong \bigoplus_{g \in E} Ind_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}^{K} Res_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}^{gHg^{-1}}gM$, a K-isomorphism where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $E$ is the set of representative classes for double cosets $KgH$, $Ind$ is the induction and $Res$ is the restriction of scalars.

I just put a picture here
[image]

Now i cant seem to prove this part b), the only thing i think its true is that $Ind_{H}^GM \cong \bigoplus_{g\in E} Ind_{K \cap gHg^{-1}}^K gM$ and then i guess we have to take $Res$ but i cant see why this would swich with $Ind$ and why those subgroups would appear. Any tips or advice are aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this known as Mackey's formula ?  As for the formula you get, note that it doesn't make sense : $gM$ is not a $K\cap gHg^{-1}$ representation, it's a $gHg^{-1}$-representation : this explains the internal $Res$ term. As for the outer term, note that the isomorphism you get still doesn't make sense, because $Ind^K$ makes the thing a $K$-representation, while on the right you have a $G$-representation. I think you should redo your proof (which is probably just fine) while taking extra precautions/care with respect to what group is acting

Comment: (what I mean is : I think your proof is essentially correct, except when you consider the typing : what is a $G$-representation, what is a $K$-representation etc. If you type it well, you should get the given formula - your formula isn't well-typed)

Comment: I dont think i understand what you are saying because it seems to me you are talking about representation theory wich i know almost zero about, im just taking about this in context of reduction of scalars and induction as extension of scalars.

Comment: Well it's essentially the same thing : take a ring $R$ with a subring $S$. Given a $R$-module $M$, you can consider it an $S$-module with "the same" action. But if you write that new module $M$ too, you get into trouble like typing and stuff, so you write it $Res^R_SM$. Here you have that issue : $gM$ is not a $K\cap gHg^{-1}$-module, it's a $gHg^{-1}$-module, so $Ind_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}gM$ doesn't even make sense. Similarly, your isomorphism doesn't make sense because on the right you have a $K$-module, whereas on the right you have a $G$-module.

Comment: To solve that typing problem you just add a few $Res$ here and there, and those *don't change* the module structure, they just restrict it, so they're just here to make everything well-typed. So your isimorphism is correct, you just have to type the terms well

Comment: (Maybe it would help if you wrote down the proof you have, so we could see where the typing goes wrong, and explain how to fix it)

Comment: Just repeating what @MaximeRamzi told you, but perhaps easier to understand and apply: Whenever you write an equation between two modules, make sure they're modules over the same group. Because if they're over different groups, then they're different modules (even if they have the same elements), and so your equation couldn't possibly be true.